# Python: Getting error with installing geopandas

Tags: python, windows, geopandas

I want to install geopandas in my jupyter notebooks (Windows). So I'm using the code
`!pip install geopandas !pip install seaborn`, which didn't work at first, but after some google searches I found a possible solution. `import geopandas as gpd` gives this error message: `Could not find module 'C:\Users\**NAME**\anaconda3\Library\bin\geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.` I already tried pip install geos, but that didn't work. Does anyone know a solution that might solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!
Kind Regards,
Olivier

Comment: [installing with pip](https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-pip) seems to have some caveats, have you made sure none of those issues in the Warning section are happening?

Comment: @RandomDavis I had the Fiona warning first, but it looks solved now. That was the only error I had.